# Append time to JQuery datepicker?

Tags: jquery, time, datepicker, date-parsing

I'm trying to follow this [**example**](http://www.derekallard.com/blog/post/adding-time-to-jquery-ui-datepicker) in order to append the current time to my `input` when a date is chosen with the `datepicker`. According to the example, I should just be able to append my time string in the `dateFormat` option:

```
$("#entry_date").datepicker({dateFormat: $.datepicker.W3C + date_obj_time});
```

However, in my test (fiddle [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/NbFa6/)), the "M" in "AM" or "PM" is turning into the actual month name. For example, if I specify a date format such as this:

```
$("#DueDate").datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "mm/dd/yy 9:16 AM" );
```

I end up with this in my text field:

> 05/14/2013 9:16 A.May.

Is there a workaround for (or better way to do) this, or am I doing something blatantly wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to escape the `M` by wrapping it in single quotes.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NbFa6/1/).

[The API](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate) isn't very obvious as doesn't list it as an "escape" sequence but it lists `'...'` as being interpreted as "literal text".